# I want to open a poppup window to be open on anchor tab click

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery function which binds two td one containing name and other containing anchor tag what i want is when i click on anchor tag it should open the hrefpage in a poppup window currently now it is opening in new window or the same window.

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: "CRM_AMCInterestedData.aspx/BindGrid1",
                data: "{'hdnCompanyId':'" + ddCompanyId + "','hdnBranchId':'" + ddlBranchId + "','hdnId':'" + ddlCREId + "','FromDate':'" + txtFromDueDate + "','ToDate':'" + txtToDueDate + "'}",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#gvDetails").html("");

                    //var querystring = "Flag=AMCInterested&Branch=" + ddlBranchId + "&CRE=" + data.d[i].CRE + "&FromDate=" + txtFromDueDate + "&Todate=" + txtToDueDate + "&Status=interested&CompanyFk=" + ddCompanyId + "&EmpLoginFK=106&PageName=CRM_AMCINTERESTEDDATA.ASPX"+;
                    $('#gvDetails').append("<tr><td>CRE</td><td>Interested</td></tr>").css('background-color', '#fefefe');



                    for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {


                       //$("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].CRE + "</td><td ><a id='gvDetails'  style='color:Black' data-url =\"CRMHasDriverRefinanceDetail.aspx?Flag=AMCInterested&Branch=" + ddlBranchId + "&CRE=" + data.d[i].CRE + "&FromDate=" + txtFromDueDate + "&Todate=" + txtToDueDate + "&Status=interested&CompanyFk=" + ddCompanyId + "&EmpLoginFK=106&PageName=CRM_AMCINTERESTEDDATA.ASPX\"  href=\"javascript:void(0)\">" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a></td></tr>");

                        $("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].CRE + "</td><td><a id='#OpenDialog' rel='GB_show[1100,500]' style='color:Black' href=\"CRMHasDriverRefinanceDetail.aspx?Flag=AMCInterested&Branch=" + ddlBranchId + "&CRE=" + data.d[i].CRE + "&FromDate=" + txtFromDueDate + "&Todate=" + txtToDueDate + "&Status=interested&CompanyFk=" + ddCompanyId + "&EmpLoginFK=106&PageName=CRM_AMCINTERESTEDDATA.ASPX\">" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a></td></tr>");

                        //////$("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].CRE + "</td><td><a id='#OpenDialog' style='color:Black' href=\"CRMHasDriverRefinanceDetail.aspx?Flag=AMCInterested&Branch=" + ddlBranchId + "&CRE=" + data.d[i].CRE + "&FromDate=" + txtFromDueDate + "&Todate=" + txtToDueDate + "&Status=interested&CompanyFk=" + ddCompanyId + "&EmpLoginFK=106&PageName=CRM_AMCINTERESTEDDATA.ASPX\">" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a></td></tr>");

                    }

                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert("Error");
                }
            });

            return false;

        }
```

Thanks in advance!.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to show in the code that you posted(it is not even formatted correctly),  but based on what I understood from the situation you mentioned,  I can say that `target= "_blank"` may or may not open a new window. This behaviour can be controlled by users on their browser settings.  However,  with js,  something like this should work

```
<a href="hrefpage.html"  onclick="window.open('hrefpage.html', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=3000'); return false;"> Open Popup</a>
```

**UPDATE**:  Ok,  probably you can take care of the `href` part,  that looked pretty long for me to work on and put into above example.

Comment: Actually when i write simply </td><td><a  style='color:Black' href=\"CRMHasDriverRefinanceDetail.aspx" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a>

Comment: Actually when i write simply </td><td><a rel='GB_show[1100, 550]' style='color:Black' href=\"CRMHasDriverRefinanceDetail.aspx" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a> a popup opens but when this same code is generated using jquery like $("#gvDetails").append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].CRE + "</td><td><a rel='GB_show[1100, 550]' style='color:Black' href=\"CRMHasDriverRefinanceDetail.aspx" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a></td></tr>"); no popup opens and the page open in the same page plz suggest me something ....i have to use rel='GB_show[1100, 550]' which opens popup window

Comment: First,  you are not escaping double quotes within `href` corectly.  Second,  the reference id you use is not sufficient for appending a `<tr></tr>`,  for example, you will mess up if the table had a <tbody>.  So use something like `$('#gvDetails tr:last').append(...)`.

Comment: Try doing something like this,  report if it works: `var trgt = "CRMHasDriverRefinanceDetail.aspx?Flag=AMCInterested&Branch=" + ddlBranchId + "&CRE=" + data.d[i].CRE + "&FromDate=" + txtFromDueDate + "&Todate=" + txtToDueDate + "&Status=interested&CompanyFk=" + ddCompanyId + "&EmpLoginFK=106&PageName=CRM_AMCINTERESTEDDATA.ASPX";`  
`$('#gvDetails tr:last').append("<tr><td>" + data.d[i].CRE + "</td><td><a id='#OpenDialog' rel='GB_show[1100,500]' style='color:Black' href='" + trgt + "'>" + data.d[i].Interested + "</a></td></tr>");`

Comment: <a href="hrefpage.html"  onclick="window.open('hrefpage.html', 'newwindow', 'width=500, height=3000'); return false;"> Open Popup</a> is not working at all what i want is to open a poppup window through jquery .....